# Missing Client Certificate Chain Issue while connecting with Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, ibm-mq

There is a spring boot application that connects with a SOAP-based service. Our application has an MQ listener that receives messages from a local queue. Once a message is dequeued from that queue, it makes an API call to service.

All the communication to SOAP-based service is done via 2 way SSL.

Now we’re facing a problem while connecting with the SOAP-based service. There is a missing client certificate chain error received intermittently at the SOAP-based service end.

In our **JmsConfig** class, we’ve set concurrency on listener factory to 10 as highlighted below for having concurrent executions and parallel processing of messages from queue.

```
 @Bean
 public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(){
   DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
   try {
          factory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactoryX20()));
          factory.setConcurrency("10");
   } catch (JMSException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return factory;
 }
```

When we further call SOAP service from spring boot application once messages are consumed, missing client certificate chain error is coming in SOAP service logs for most of the messages. In a bulk load of 1k messages in the queue and with concurrent executions thereafter, around 850 messages failed at SOAP service end and only 150 passed.

Error is coming only while concurrency is set programmatically as shown via the above code snippet. If I comment out the setConcurrency call, all 1k messages get processed at SOAP service end without any certificate chain error.

Could you please have a look at our configuration and share some thoughts on why the concurrency is causing this error.

**ApplicationWebServiceImpl.java** (Calling callWebService() method from JMS listener method)

```
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
  import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
  import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
  import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessage;

  @Service
  public class ApplicationWebServiceImpl implements ApplicationWebServices {

  @Autowired
  private WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate;

  @Value("${soap.clientEndpoint}")
  private String clientEndpoint;

  @Value("${soap.action}")
  private String soapAction;

  @Override
  public Object callWebService(Object request, String serviceName) throws ClientApplicationException {

      return wsTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(clientEndpoint + serviceName, request, message -> {
          SoapMessage msg = (SoapMessage) message;
          msg.setSoapAction(soapAction + StringUtils.capitalize(serviceName));
      });
  }
}
```

**ClientApplication** (Spring boot main class)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.abc.ca")    
public class ClientApplication {

  @Value(value = "${cert.keyStoreFileName}")
  private String keyStoreFileName;

  @Value(value = "${cert.trustStoreFileName}")
  private String trustStoreFileName;

  @Value(value = "${cert.disabledAlgorithms}")
  private String disabledAlgorithms;

  @PostConstruct
  public void getKeyTrustStore() {
      Security.setProperty("jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms", disabledAlgorithms);
      String filePath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(keyStoreFileName).getFile();

      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", filePath);
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeme");
      filePath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(trustStoreFileName).getFile();      

      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", filePath);
      System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeme");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(ClientApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this related to IBM MQ?  It seems the actual cert issue is with your SOAP service call not with MQ?

Comment: Yes it is IBM MQ. The certificate issue is with SOAP service call. When concurrency is not set, the SOAP service is processing the 1k load perfectly fine. When I set concurrency to 10 at MQ config class, for some messages, the SOAP service is giving missing client certificate chain error.

Comment: As you are setting concurrency to more than 1, you will be introducing concurrency into your application. Your application will need to ensure that the required client certificate chain is available for each consumer to use. I suspect that you have variables either going out of scope or being dropped, before they can be used. So as @JoshMc suggests the error is most likely in your logic invoking the SOAP service not being concurrent safe. You should share that logic, so we can help identify if that is the problem.

Comment: Hi, I've shared the service calling code and also the class where certificates are set.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, I've resolved above problem by explicitly calling setMessageSender on wsTemplate and setting HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender.

Thanks @chughts for giving me a pointer.

Cheers!

```
 wsTemplate.setMessageSender(httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender());

 @Bean 
 public HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender() throws Exception { 
     HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender = new 
                HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();

    httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender.setTrustManagers(
            loadDefaultTrustStore());

    httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender.setKeyManagers(
            loadKeyStore());

    httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() { 
       @Override 
       public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) { 
          if ("localhost".equals(hostname)) { 
            return true; 
          } 
          return false; 
       } 
    });     
    return httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender; 
}

private KeyManager[] loadKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException,
     FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
     CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

     KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");

     FileInputStream fileInputStreamKeyStore = new FileInputStream("/ca/appKeystore.jks");
     keyStore.load(fileInputStreamKeyStore,"changeme".toCharArray());

     KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
            .getDefaultAlgorithm());        
     keyFactory.init(keyStore,"changeme".toCharArray());
     return keyFactory.getKeyManagers();
}

private TrustManager[] loadDefaultTrustStore() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                KeyStoreException {
     TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = 
     TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
        .getDefaultAlgorithm());
     trustFactory.init((KeyStore)null);     
     return trustFactory.getTrustManagers();
}
```